# I can't use two OnClickListeners?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to use two OnClickListeners but I cant figure out how to do it right.

Could anyone help me fix my code?

```
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View paramView) {

                                    numBase.getText().clear();
                                    numNikotin.getText().clear();

                                }

            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // I basically want this onClick Listener for the btnClear aswell, but I just cant get both to work. If I take away the btnClear setOnCLickListener Event then btnAdd works just fine.

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(numBase.getText().toString());
                    num2 = Double.parseDouble(numNikotin.getText().toString());

                    sum = num1 / 20 * num2;
                    String resultN = String.format("%.2f%%", Double.toString(sum));
                    addResult.setText(resultN);

                    sum = num1 - sum;
                    String resultB = String.format("%.2f%%", Double.toString(sum));
                    addResult2.setText(resultB);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot do that. Just split the shared code between two button to another method and call in inside two listener.

```
private foo() {
     num1 = Double.parseDouble(numBase.getText().toString());
     num2 = Double.parseDouble(numNikotin.getText().toString());

     sum = num1 / 20 * num2;
     String resultN = String.format("%.2f%%", Double.toString(sum));
     addResult.setText(resultN);

     sum = num1 - sum;
     String resultB = String.format("%.2f%%", Double.toString(sum));
     addResult2.setText(resultB);
}


 btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View paramView) {
             numBase.getText().clear();
             numNikotin.getText().clear();
             foo();

     }
});


btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
              foo();
       }
});
```

Comment: @CagriYalcin tell me why?

Comment: If i'm right, he wants to click clear button, and then click the add button. I mean he must clear his text to add a new one.

Comment: @CagriYalcin if so, he should call performClick() inside addButton click listener, right?

Comment: @GeniusQ you are right he should use **`performClick()`**

Comment: Or he can use setEnabled() maybe ? i didn't use performClick() before.

Comment: @CagriYalcin **[performClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)** -> **Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                numBase.getText().clear();
                                numNikotin.getText().clear(); 
                                btnAdd.performClick();
                            }
                        });

btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                num1 = Double.parseDouble(numBase.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(numNikotin.getText().toString());

                sum = num1 / 20 * num2;
                String resultN = String.format("%.2f%%", Double.toString(sum));
                addResult.setText(resultN);

                sum = num1 - sum;
                String resultB = String.format("%.2f%%", Double.toString(sum));
                addResult2.setText(resultB);
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
use **[performClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)**

> **`public boolean performClick ()`**
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined.
>
> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc

```
btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    btnAdd.performClick();
                                    numBase.getText().clear();
                                    numNikotin.getText().clear(); 
                                }
                            });
```

than create a separate click listener for `btnAdd`

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            num1 = Double.parseDouble(numBase.getText().toString());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(numNikotin.getText().toString());

            sum = num1 / 20 * num2;
            String resultN = String.format("%.2f%%", Double.toString(sum));
            addResult.setText(resultN);

            sum = num1 - sum;
            String resultB = String.format("%.2f%%", Double.toString(sum));
            addResult2.setText(resultB);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this out.

Comment: @tegabyte let me know if any query

Comment: I will let you know whenever I get to fix it in Android Studio. Curently at work so I wont be able to do the same thing all the time. Might take 15 minutes.